# RewriteRule not executing properly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following directory structure:

```
public_html/sites/site_a/
public_html/sites/site_b/
```

I am trying to write a `.htaccess` for `site_a` that rewrites urls. I have the following sitting in the root directory of `site_a`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \?page=([a-z]*) $1 [L,QSA]
```

Basically I would like to have my urls:

```
http://hostname/sites/site_a/?page=products
```

Show as:

```
http://hostname/sites/site_a/products
```

However this doesn't seem to work. The page shows with the full url.

Comment: You cannot access GET parameters in a rewriting rule like this. They are not part of the url, actually. That is documented. But you can evaluate the QUERY_STRING the module provides for this. Read the excellent documentation, it is all explained in there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sites/site_a/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+sites/site_a/\?page=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ ?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

in the htaccess file in your `site_a` directory.

Comment: OMG... at first I was starting to think my host doesn't support mod_rewrite... But you sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Thank you so much. Now I'm going to study this answer and figure it out piece by piece to find out what you did, why you did it. Thank you!!!

Comment: Actually now there is a new problem. This `http://hostname/sites/site_a/?page=products` becomes this: `http://hostname/sites/site_a/products`... which is correct. But when I click another link on my site it shows this: `http://hostname/sites/site_a/products?page=products`

Comment: @JTFRage The first rule takes requests for `?page=something` and **redirects the browser** to the URL which doesn't have the query string. The redirect changes what's in the URL address bar. The second rule internally rewrites it **back** to the query string

Comment: @JTFRage you either need a `<base href="/sites/site_a/">` in the header of your pages or you need to change all your links so that they look like `products` isntead of `?page=products`

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I guess I just have to change all my `<a href="?page=products">Products</a>` to just `<a href="products">Products</a>` right?

Comment: @JTFRage yeah, as long as there's no `/` in there it should be fine